# Variance of square of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

Let $q_{i}$ be a random variable having the Binomial distribution with number of trials $2^{n}$ and success probability $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm trying to find the variance of
the random variable

\begin{equation}
p_{i} = \bigg(\frac{2}{2^{n}}~ q_{i} - 1 \bigg)^{2}.
\end{equation}

Comment: @AaronHendrickson The expected value may be a lot simpler than that, perhaps $2^{-n}$

Comment: Yes, the expected value is $2^{-n}$. Is there any way to simplify the variance?

Comment: Yes there is.  One approach might be to look at the kurtosis of a binomial random variable.  Another might be to look at $n=0,1,2,3$ and try to spot the pattern: the answer seems to be a fraction with denominator $2^{3n}$ or perhaps $2^{3n-1}$ and a numerator which is a simple function of $2^n$

Comment: Can you expand your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider for $n=0,1,2,3$ so $2^n=1,2,4,8$, you get

```
n    2^n        E[p]               Var(p)
                                   
0     1           1                   0
1     2     0.5   = 1/2    0.25       = 1/2^2 
2     4     0.25  = 1/4    0.0935     = 3/2^5
3     8     0.125 = 1/8    0.02734375 = 7/2^8
```

which suggest a mean of $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ and variance of $\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^{3n-1}}$

and if we let $m=2^n$ then they suggest a mean of $\dfrac{1}{m}$ and variance of $\dfrac{2}{m^2}-\dfrac{2}{m^3}$.

As for a proof, consider $q$ as a binomial random variable with parameters $m$ and $\frac12$:

$q$ has mean $\frac{m}{2}$ and variance $\frac{m}{4}$ and excess kurtosis $-\frac{2}{m}$,

so $\mathbb E\left[\frac2m q-1\right]=0$ and thus, with $p=\left(\frac2m q-1\right)^2$, you can say

- $\mathbb E[p]=\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac2m q-1\right)^2\right]=\text{Var}\left(\frac2m q-1\right)=\text{Var}\left(\frac2m q\right)=\left(\frac2m\right)^2\frac{m}{4}=\frac{1}{m},$
- $\mathbb E[p^2]=\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac2m q-1\right)^4\right]=\left(\frac2m\right)^4\left(3-\frac{2}{m}\right)\left(\frac{m}{4}\right)^2=\frac{3}{m^2}-\frac2{m^3},$
- $\text{Var}(p)= \left(\frac{3}{m^2}-\frac2{m^3}\right) -\left(\frac1m\right)^2 = \frac{2}{m^2}-\frac2{m^3}.\qquad \square$

Comment: Where do we use a property of excess kurtois? What is that property?

Comment: @RandomMatrices The excess kurtosis of $-\frac{2}{m}$ means a total kurtosis of $3-\frac{2}{m}$ as the ratio of the fourth moment of $q$ about its mean to the square of its second moment about its mean.  This allows you to find $\mathbb E[p^2]$